# How can I sort a nested dictionary without using Lambda or ItemGetter?

Tags: python

Here's an example for what I am looking for. My previous code if I wanted to sort by last name:

```
from operator import getitem
main_dict = {}
main_dict['Kevin'] = {'ID': '1', 'Last Name': 'Jones', 'First Name': 'Kevin'}
main_dict['David'] = {'ID': '2', 'Last Name': 'Walker', 'First Name': 'David'}
sorted_lastname = sorted(main_dict.items(), key=lambda x: getitem(x[1], 'Last Name'))
print(sorted_lastname)
```

How can I sort this without the use of Lambda and itemgetter?

Comment: Define a regular function with `def` and pass it as `key` argument?

Comment: @buran Can I get an example? Thank you very much for your response?

Answer (score 1):

This is how to implement @buran's idea.

```
def func(tup):
    key, d = tup
    return d['Last Name']

main_dict = {}
main_dict['Kevin'] = {'ID': '1', 'Last Name': 'Jones', 'First Name': 'Kevin'}
main_dict['David'] = {'ID': '2', 'Last Name': 'Walker', 'First Name': 'David'}
sorted_lastname = sorted(main_dict.items(), key=func)
print(sorted_lastname)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use normal function

```
main_dict = {}
main_dict['Kevin'] = {'ID': '1', 'Last Name': 'Jones', 'First Name': 'Kevin'}
main_dict['David'] = {'ID': '2', 'Last Name': 'Walker', 'First Name': 'David'}

def func(item):
    return item[1]['Last Name']

sorted_lastname = sorted(main_dict.items(), key=func)

print(sorted_lastname)
```